# Twilio Programmable Video API desynchronization between audio and video on the receiver's end

Tags: javascript, twilio, web-audio-api, twilio-api

I'm using *twilio-video.js* to create a WebRTC video connection between two clients. To the basic camera and microphone tracks, I add an additional sound stream, created from loading a music file and getting a `MediaStream` out of it through Web Audio API. It's then turned into Twilio's `LocalAudioTrack` and streamed to the other peer.

The problem is, even though everything's working correctly on both sides, the receiving peer experiences slight (but unacceptable for my use-case) resynchronization between the microphone & camera vs additional sound. It's sometimes ahead and sometimes behind the microphone & camera input when compared to what the streaming peer is experiencing.

I sadly cannot share any code, but I hope I described my issue clearly.

Comment: you might want to file an issue on https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues instead. They can ask question that allow them better investigation.

Comment: What have you tried to synchronize them together? A code would be useful, I think you might be making some mistake with timing both in the code.